# Spring Security OAuth2 Jwt Access Denied

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, postman

I'm trying to do this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_oauth2_with_jwt.htm about Spring Security and OAuth2, Spring boot 1.5. i can get the access token. but when i try to get the endpoint i get access denied error in Postman. I m working on Mac os.

[image]

[image]

configure Methode

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);
    }
```

In tokenEnhancer Method i commented the public key, because i had an error about Mac verification

```
@Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenEnhancer() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey(privateKey);
        //converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);
        return converter;
    }
```

Comment: 403 error means that user is authenticated but doesn't have right for access. User not authorized. Could you show your configure(HttpSecurity http) method?

Answer (score 0):

Users which have appropriate GrantedAuthority should have access to endpoints and it's possible to achieve by next settings.

For instance

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/products/**").hasRole("USER")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);
}
```

On the other hand need to know 'role' of user.

It's possible to check in db or other places which persist this info.

Or need to find method which define Principle of current user. It's depend on type of authentication. Implementation of method `doFilterInternal` [OncePerRequestFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html) abstract class responsible of defining Priciple.